# How to make the project structure visible in JIRA agile - independent of EPICS

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I plan to use JIRA-Agile as used to:
EPIC->US->Task

Nevertheless, the JIRA is not only used by one project but rather by a couple of projects, which cooperate or even interfere in a few topics.

At the end I want to mark up which EPIC belongs to which project. I thought about to use labels or components, but for me it seems not very suitable. What is the best (may even standard) way representing this project structure above the EPIC level ?

Features I need:

- Epic can belong to more than one Project
- Epic can be shifted between projects
- Projects existing on different levels (one Project can even combine 2 smaller one)
- "nearly" automatic reporting export is possible
- Project structure can be "read" from the Jira

Comment: You seem to be combining several questions here. Would it be possible to split them out in to separate posts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Comment: This question is more likely to be on-topic at [softwareengineering.se].

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about project management and analysis in jira.?
if so then you can see if the Jira Portfolio management app works for you

https://www.atlassian.com/blog/jira-service-desk/portfolio-for-jira-2-0-is-here

I am not sure how Epic will help in your case -- lets hear more answers here.

Comment: Thanks, thats an interesting tool, which I should may consider for reporting. Nevertheless, my question rather deals about "how to structure" the projects and epics. I have a couple of projects (lets say 1-4) running in parallel. They all interact with project 5 (for example handing over Epics and issues), and there is a project 6 which is partially involved in project 1+2+5. I would like to have like a combined backlog for all - although the issues should be able to "link" to one or more projects separately.

Comment: @Marcus based on my understanding, looks like u need to see many sprints running in various projects  and all these in a single view.

Comment: Yes, that would partially solve the problem - but I am not sure if I can combine different "projects" in the same view...

Answer (score 0):

Well i am not sure if a jql will make it happen, but https://softwareplant.com/jira-aggregate-multiple-sprints-single-screen/ could help you.!

it has an option to view the board based on Epic, userstory also.!